# How to add DL support to docco.coffee?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, documentation, markdown

I was reading this documentation on [Markdown in Python](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Definition_Lists), and I think it would be really helpful for documenting function arguments to use . Do you know how to make docco capable of "understanding" that syntax and turning it into a ?

(Maybe someone could also create the docco.coffe tag as well...)

Thanks,

Óscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docco.coffee uses [Showdown.js](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) to process Markdown, so you'd want to identify [which branch](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown/network) 
 goes into making the node package `npm install docco` installs and then, after confirming that it doesn't support definition lists under a different syntax, write a patch for it.